# What would be a pseudocode of try-catch pattern, common in generally all programming languages?

Tags: pseudocode

What would be a pseudocode of try-catch pattern, common in generally all programming languages?

**Perhaps the following?**

```
Try X,
If you catch Y (success) than continue,
If you didn't catch Y (bug),
Either,
Do nothing || throw an exception (error)
```

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148870/755

Answer (score 1):

Just copy what you found in *some* language. As long as it is reasonable clear it’s fine. For example

```
Do
    Statement 1
    Try statement 2
    Try statement 3
    Statement 4
    Throw some exception
Catch exception type 1
    Actions
Catch exception type 2
    Actions
Catch
    Re-throw exception
End do
```

So you have one block covered by catch blocks, containing statements that can or can’t throw exceptions, handling for different classes of exceptions, “throw” to throw an exception and “rethrow” for throwing an exception that was just caught instead of handling it.

This is modelled on Swift which doesn’t allow surprising exceptions.