# What is a pseudocode of try-catch?

Tags: programming-languages, pseudocode

What is a pseudocode of try-catch? Is it this?

```
**Try** SOMETHING

If you succeed
    Do nothing special
Else, if you didn't succeed
    Do what's described in the **Catch** block
Anyway, either if you succeeded or failed
    Do what's described in the **Finally** block (if there is one)
```

### Update

I aim to find the pseudocode that will reflect the logic of every `try...catch` pattern in generally any modern abstract programming language (such as JavaScript, PHP, Python, etc.).

I might have found it already (the one above), and I basically ask for an affirmation.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148628/755

Comment: Hello @D.W. I myself posted that linked post but I was sure that I was misunderstood so I consulted a programmer and from that consultation understood that indeed my post wasn't understood and I should publish another one, more precise to the point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last `Else`, which doesn't seem to have anything nested under it. If you meant `End if`, then that description is usable, although as noted by others it doesn't capture all the details. If you meant to indent the Finally line inside the `Else`, then it's incorrect; in most languages, the `Finally` clause is always executed, even if another exception is thrown in the `Catch` clause (although that's one of the details which might not always be that simple to describe).

Comment: @rici thanks a lot, I have edited the pseudocode, would you say it's more accurate at the moment?

Comment: That's an improvement, yes. If it helps you understand the concept, that's cool. But the details are important; the failure can occur anywhere down the call stack, in a different scope. In languages where leaving a scope involves immediate object destruction, the details of how the stack is unwound are hard to express using your pseudocode description.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode for `try`-`catch` is

```
try:
  〈some-code〉
catch:
  〈exception-handling-code〉
```

My point is that *pseudocode* is not a well-defined concept but an informal way of displaying algorithms. You thus have the freedom to adapt the pseudocode so that it reflects the control-flow and other features of the computation that you would like to present.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to express exception handling in pseudocode like that, because exception handling allows for non-local returns at arbitrary points. That is, even the line "try something" doesn't express what's going on.

So your pseudocode would really need to encompass the code of the "something" you're trying as well. The normal way to express this would be with a tagged union return type like  the `Result` type in Rust, which can express both the desired return value and a "did not return properly" value. Even then, to properly demonstrate the behavior of the construct you'll need a type hierarchy or other way of determining whether a catch clause attaches to a particular exception, otherwise there's no way to demonstrate propagating the exception or the Finally block.

Comment: Hello, I intuitively believe that virtually all abstract modern programming languages (JS, PHP, Python, Ruby, C#, Go) do have the same general logical pattern for `try...catch` keywords. I would desire to know if I'm wrong...

Comment: @alistro Yes, that's broadly correct, though there are differences in the process of exception matching (and, of course, in implementation).

Comment: Hello again Sneftel, what did you mean with `non-local returns at arbitrary points`? Sorry I am quite new to Computer Science. You may want to update the answer with a footenote explanation or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal standard for pseudocode.  It is unlikely that you will find something that encompasses every possible exception pattern in every modern language.  Instead, pseudocode is a form of informal communication.  As long as it is clear to the reader, you are probably fine.  I encourage you to focus on clarity of communication in your specific situation, not trying to identify a single pseudocode syntax that covers all possible cases that might ever arise.

Comment: I understand, but surely you would agree that in generally all modern abstract programming languages there is indeed one pattern we can deduct / reduce ... The reason I seek to deduct / reduce it is because I had hard time understanding a few JavaScript and PHP try-catch codes I read but the pseudocode was very easy for me.